# state errors with Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm new to Android programming and am building a simple app that plays a sound from a local file when you flip the phone over, using a `SensorListener` for the accelerometer. Additionally, there's an image with a click listener that also plays the same sound when touched.

My code has the following sequence:

`onCreate` and `onRestart` - call `MediaPlayer.create()` for the local file.

`onDestroy` - call `MediaPlayer.release` and set the reference to null.

I'm debugging the app on my phone since the emulator doesn't support accelerometers.
When I click the image, I get a `start called in state 64` error in Logcat, and when I flip the phone, the app FCs with a `NullPointerException` when `mp.start()` is called.

My understanding of how it works, from the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) documentation is that you have to call `create()`, which in turn calls `prepare()` before you can start or stop the player. Is there a problem with the sequence of steps?

I've also tried releasing the media player in `onStop`, to no avail.

I have the following sensor listener for the accelerometer (mp is the `MediaPlayer` object) -

```
    private final SensorEventListener accelerometerListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {

        float z_value = arg0.values[2];

        if (z_value < 0 && playerReady) {
            mp.start(); //  <-- NullPointerException thrown here.
        } else {
            mp.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};
```

..and the following click listener for the button -

```
    private final View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (playerReady) {
            mp.start();
        }
    }
};
```

I also wrote an `onPreparedListener` for the media player (which sets the `playerReady` seen above)

```
    private final OnPreparedListener opl = new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        playerReady = true;
    }
};
```

*Edit*  Here's `onCreate()` and `onRestart()` -

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Moo.this, R.raw.moo);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(opl);
    ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    im.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager
            .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (sensorList.size() > 0) {
        accelerometerPresent = true;
        accelerometerSensor = sensorList.get(0);
        sensorManager.registerListener(accelerometerListener,
                accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Moo.this, R.raw.moo);
}
```

Comment: `mp` is null. where is it initialized?

Comment: in onCreate() & onRestart.

Comment: Yeah, I've added that as well.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/k-QwQ0O4UCE

Comment: thanks, let me try with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44588/discussion-between-rex-and-raghunandan)

Comment: See this answer here it uses accelerometer and play sound when it changes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7293430/1979347